# HDD allocation fstab

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, hard-disk, fstab

In my PC running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I have installed three SATA hard drives. Two of them are installed near a cooler. I want to physically switch two drives (one that is not near the fan should be moved near the fan). How would Ubunutu deal with the switch? The device names in fstab, are they in any way relying on the sata port that they are connected to on my motherboard?

EDIT:

This is my /etc/fstab

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc                                       /proc             proc  nodev,noexec,nosuid  0  0  
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=f04e6038-4412-46c4-b58d-67bfe3f8eddd  /                 ext4  errors=remount-ro    0  1  
# /Volumes/Backup was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=dc25bafb-adbc-4a65-845c-02c9253a795e  /Volumes/Backup   ext4  defaults             0  2  
# /Volumes/Storage was on /dev/sdc1 during installation
UUID=74867f3e-acda-4efc-a6aa-7d21484d64a4  /Volumes/Storage  ext4  defaults             0  2  
/dev/sdc2                                  /Volumes/Storage  ext4  defaults             0  0  
#/dev/sdc1                                  /media/sdc1       swap  sw                   0  0 
/dev/sdc1        none        swap        defaults        0        0
```

EDIT (changed /etc/fstab according to comments):

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>                            <mount point>             <type>  <options>            <dump>  <pass>
proc                                       /proc                     proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid  0       0  
UUID=f04e6038-4412-46c4-b58d-67bfe3f8eddd  /                         ext4    errors=remount-ro    0       1  
UUID=dc25bafb-adbc-4a65-845c-02c9253a795e  /Volumes/Backup           ext4    defaults             0       2  
UUID=74867f3e-acda-4efc-a6aa-7d21484d64a4  /Volumes/Storage          ext4    defaults             0       2   
UUID=88ee73e8-7556-40fa-b696-fbc15161036b  none                      swap    defaults             0       0
```

Comment: Why are you mounting `/Volumes/Storage` twice?

Comment: I have no clue. I did not put it there myself. The only thing I added is the swap partition. Any tips on pruning my fstab file would be welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The UUIDs don't change when you reorder the drives. However, your
`sdc?` entries might change. It's best practice not to rely on the
`sd?` numbering. Better use UUIDs or LABELs to address your
partitions.

**Find the UUID or LABEL**

as root:

```
blkid -o list -c /dev/null
```

**Change the entries**

Change the entries that use the `/dev/sd?` syntax (in your case `/dev/sdc1`) to use either the UUID or the LABEL, if the file system has one. Use the values from the `blkid` output.

```
UUID=24467f3e-bcda-5efc-a6aa-7d21384d64a4
LABEL=swap
```

Comment: So what would you suggest me to change in my /etc/fstab file before I switch the drives?

Comment: I edited my question to make it clear. And remove the redundant mount (the line starting with `/dev/sdc2`).

Comment: can I also remove the lines starting with # [...] was on [...] during installation  ?

Comment: I followed directions (i think) and came up with an improved fstab file (see my original post). Does it look ok to you?

Comment: That is a beautiful and well-written `fstab`. Now you can safely reorder the disks.